# Facebook API process shared object

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need some help with graph api. I need to process shared objects of a message. When I call "shares" edge of a message, I'm getting:

```
{'data': [{'id': '123980935012069',
       'link': 'https://www.facebook.com/physicstutorial/jobs/1923839241194493/applications/1898458643751655/',
       'name': 'Application to Tutoring'}],
       'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MAZDZD', 'before': 'MAZDZD'},
       'next':'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/mid.$cAAHdCLroA9hky9RD5Femo76q5Xln/shares?access_token='}
}
```

The link point to the object which Im interested. But I cannot process it in api. I tried to get it directly like "https://graph.facebook.com/123980935012069" but I'm getting:

```
{
 "error": {
 "message": "(#12) singular links API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
 "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 12,
 "fbtrace_id": "Byd4+EM2UM9"
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:**
Now I'm trying to fetch like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{page_id}_{object_id}?access_token={page_access_token]'
```

And getting:

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '
"'ID_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to "
'missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

Comment: I'm keep getting:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1027664347329387_486826835017714' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "DgBkJXARad/"
   }
}
All permissions are enabled on the page now. Looks like this is another case.

Comment: "This does not really answer the question" this is what I got from "dublicated" question.